# How to create multiple pages if there were too many for one page?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a django project trying to create a forum. Now when a certain number of objects (thread-previews) is reached on one page, I want a second (and then third page etc) page created and some of these objects should go to these next pages (page 2, then page 3 etc.) and the url for the second page should be something like "mysite.com/fourum/topic/2" and so on.

And then there have to be some buttons to navigate to page 2, page 3 etc.

This would be relevant code:

gaming.html

```html
{% extends "forum/index.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Gaming {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="main-container">
    <h1 class="heading">Forum: Gaming</h1>
    {% for obj in object %}
        <div class="username">{{obj.username}}</div>
        <div class="date">{{obj.date}}</div>
        <div class="topic">{{obj.topic}}</div>
        <div class="title"><a class="link" href="{{obj.slug_titel}}">{{obj.title}}</a></div>
        <div class="content">{{obj.content}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```py
def gaming(request):
    obj = Threads.objects.filter(topic="gaming")
    context = {
        "object": obj,
    }
    return render(request, "forum/gaming.html", context)
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=django+paging+OR+pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you describe looks like django pagination.

Within your view, something as follow could do the trick :

```
...
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
...
    def gaming(request):
        threads = Threads.objects.filter(topic="gaming")
        paginator = Paginator(threads, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page.
    
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        return render(request, "forum/gaming.html", {'page_obj': page_obj, **context})
```

On the template add following :

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Beside i recommend you to read the documentation about the subject : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/pagination/